# How to analyse the resilience of banks during financial crises using linear regression and other statistical methods?

Tags: statistics, finance-mathematics, mathematics, statistical-finance

I am a student in finance and have to work on a project for the semester.

I have to study the difference of resilience during financial crises between the 5 biggest US banks and the 5 biggest Canadian banks.

I know that Canadian banks are praised for their resilience and strong regulations.

That is why I chose the following hypothesis that I want to prove: ***Canadian banks are more resilient than U.S. banks during periods of financial turmoil.***

**My teacher wants me to use statistical methods** to support my hypothesis, these methods include linear regression, variances analysis, means analysis, etc.

However, my first results are really disappointing and I wanted to have your point of view regarding what I have been doing until now.

I decided to start with the linear regression on Excel to see if I get results that could support my hypothesis.

I am currently studying 10 banks, 5 Canadian and 5 American.

**Canadian banks:**

- TD Bank
- Bank of Montreal (BMO)
- Royal Bank of Canada (RBC)
- The Bank of Nova Scotia
- The Canadian Imperial Bank of Commerce (CIBC)

**American banks:**

- Bank of America
- Wells Fargo
- JPMorgan
- Citigroup
- US Bancorp

For my first linear regression, I took one dependent variable (y) and three independent variables (x1), (x2), and (x3).

**For my dependent variable (y)**, I chose to use the Return on Asset (ROA) of each banks from Q1 1997 to Q4 2022. Which represent 104 observations which I think is enough for my linear regression.

**For my independent variables (x1), (x2), and (x3)**, I used:

- (x1): national inflation rates (%)
- (x2): national unemployment rates (%)
- (x3): national GDP

*My data sources are Capital IQ for financial data and OECD.*

My idea behind this regression is that, is there is a lower correlation between the bank's ROA and the three independent variables, it means that the bank is less impacted by the global financial and economical situation of the country and therefore, more resilient.
On the other side, if there is a higher correlation, it means that the bank is more easily impacted, and therefore, less resilient.

However, I am very disappointed by my results. T**he average R and R² of Canadian banks are respectively 0.43 and 0.20 and for U.S. banks they are around 0.45 and 0.22.** There is a slight difference but nothing crazy. I was expecting a bit more to be honest.

And for the P-values, they are often above 0.05 which, if I am not wrong, is not great. (Should be lower than 0.05)

Can I have your thoughts on my subject? Do you think I am missing something or just not during it the right way?

I would be glad to have your reviews and suggestions. It would greatly help me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe the conclusion is simply that no data  supports the hypothesis?

Comment: That's what I thought about. But if it is true that Canadian banks have stronger regulations than U.S. banks, there should be a way to see this in a way or another, right? Statisticly talking

Comment: For "resilience of banks during financial crisis" you might look at a different variable than ROA (which is more a measure of lg term profitability), for example the behavior of the bank stocks during a period of "financial crisis" which you would select by some criterion (maybe look at the recent period following the failure of SVB? How were different bank stock affected?).

Comment: I'm honestly not sure that this is true. For example, :) I recall how a few years ago Buenos Aires staff of one of the banks you mention evacuated from their offices to the airport via helicopter, whilst Argenrine police were coming in cars to arrest them. I don't recall this happening at American banks. I'm not sure whether/how to include such events in a measure of resiliency.

Comment: Yiur premise is similar to the opinion, held by many Canadians, that their socialized healthcare is better than the U.S. It is better by some objective measures, such as the cost per patient. It is not better when some patients have to choose between waiting months for treatment in Canada or visiting the U.S.  for treatment. Or maybe it is, when you'te not that patient or their family member.

Comment: So, if my hypothesis is wrong, how can I prove it is wrong? I'm thinking about making a linear regression between market cap and inflation, GDP and unemployment. Any ideas of additional variables I could try? That would be welcomed

Comment: Very well, how about counting policitians' pronouncements calling their banks "resilient"? E..g. https://twitter.com/cafreeland/status/1635803079772708865  Surely, Canada would be ahead of the world on this score. For extra credit, use the terms "free ride" and "cherry picking" in context.  And you could regress it, e.g. against the number of bank accounts frozen because the depositors were political enemies of the current governmemt https://c2cjournal.ca/2022/05/frozen-how-canadas-banks-betrayed-their-customers-during-the-emergencies-act/

Comment: Canadian politicians often claim that the "big 6" banks that you list were not "bailed out" in 2008. However, in reality: https://www.cbc.ca/news/business/banks-got-114b-from-governments-during-recession-1.1145997 and https://globalnews.ca/news/239714/canadas-big-banks-received-114-billion-in-bailouts-study/ . Also, here's some libertarian think tank's take on the sordid Argentine affair https://www.cato.org/commentary/canada-sleeps-argentina-plunders (for the record, I side with Argentine on this one).

Comment: While at it, look at the correlation between the number of sexual misconduct accusations against Canada's hereditary prime minister https://macleans.ca/news/canada/justin-trudeaus-reported-kokanee-grope-matters-but-not-for-the-obvious-reason/ and insolvencies https://ised-isde.canada.ca/site/office-superintendent-bankruptcy/en/statistics-and-research/insolvency-statistics-canada-january-2023 - up 15% in January.